# e2e ionic2 test code does not work

Tags: angular, protractor, ionic2

I am trying to write an e2e for my app using protractor
this is my login page of my app

```
<ion-navbar *navbar primary>
    <ion-title>{{config.organization}} - Login</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>

        <form #loginForm="ngForm" novalidate>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating primary>Username</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="userProvider.userName" (change)='onUserNameChange()' ngControl="username" type="text" #username="ngForm" id='userNameField' required>
                </ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <p [hidden]="username.valid || submitted == false" danger padding-left>
                Username is required
            </p>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating primary>Password</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="userProvider.password" (change)='onPasswordChange()' ngControl="password" type="password" #password="ngForm" id='passwordField' required>
                </ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <p [hidden]="password.valid || submitted == false" danger padding-left>
                Password is required
            </p>

            <ion-row responsive-sm >
                <button  (click)="onLogin(loginForm)" id="logInButton" type="submit" primary round>Login</button>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-item>
                Server: {{ob3URL}}
            </ion-item>


            <ion-row [hidden]='!wrongCredential'>
                <p danger class='errorElement'>
                    Username / Password is wrong
                </p>
            </ion-row>

        </form>

    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

in my spec file i used this

```
it('should start with empty fields',() => {
        expect((element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(0)).toContain(""))
    });
```

to check weather the page has data on page load but when i execute this i get an error in my terminal
app/pages/login/login.e2e.ts (21,60): Property 'toContain' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'. (2339)

if i send keys it send keys in that text box but i could not check it by using toBe(""),toContain('') i could not expect any of this
could someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property 'toContain' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.

Several problems here:

- you've mixed up the quotes. `toContain()` needs to be called on the result of `expect()`
- since you need to check that the input field is empty, you need to use `toEqual("")` on the `value` attribute of the input
- I don't see an element with `text-input` class in the HTML you have posted, but I assume you know what you are locating at this point

Fixed version:

```
expect(element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(0).getAttribute("value")).toEqual("");
```